# Unable to add successful sudoer entry for single command

Tags: sudo

I'm attempting to add an entry to `/etc/sudoers` to run a specific command that needs sudo permission but I don't want it to require a password.  But no matter what I've tried, I can't get it to have affect.  The [man](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sudoers.5.html) page indicates the format is:

```
<user>     <system> = [NOPASSWD|PASSWD]: <command> [, <command>]
ray        rushmore = NOPASSWD: /bin/kill, /bin/ls, /usr/bin/lprm
```

So, I have entered:

```
%users   ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/kbd_backlight
```

I also tried specifically using my username and system name but it made no difference. Executing the command `kbd_backlight` still prompts for a password.

Comment: Did you really execute the command `kbd_backlight` - or was it `sudo kbd_backlight`?

Comment: Just kbd_backlight.  And it prompted which I did not expect it to do.

Comment: You will need to use `sudo kbd_backlight` to make use of the configuration in `/etc/sudoers` - otherwise it likely uses the polkit authentication mechanism

Comment: Since this was a script that works upon a device, I ended up switching to use udev rules to provide the access.  See this project: https://github.com/yusefnapora/pixelbook-linux/blob/master/implementation-details.md#keyboard-backlight